# Nearest neighbor join with distance condition

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, geopandas

In this question I'm reffering to this project:

> https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/master/notebooks/L3/nearest-neighbor-faster.html

We have two GeoDataFrames:

Buildings:

```
             name                   geometry
0            None  POINT (24.85584 60.20727)
1     Uimastadion  POINT (24.93045 60.18882)
2            None  POINT (24.95113 60.16994)
3  Hartwall Arena  POINT (24.92918 60.20570)
```

and Bus stops:

```
     stop_name   stop_lat   stop_lon  stop_id                   geometry
0  Ritarihuone  60.169460  24.956670  1010102  POINT (24.95667 60.16946)
1   Kirkkokatu  60.171270  24.956570  1010103  POINT (24.95657 60.17127)
2   Kirkkokatu  60.170293  24.956721  1010104  POINT (24.95672 60.17029)
3    Vironkatu  60.172580  24.956554  1010105  POINT (24.95655 60.17258)
```

After applying

> sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np

def get_nearest(src_points, candidates, k_neighbors=1):
    """Find nearest neighbors for all source points from a set of candidate points"""

    # Create tree from the candidate points
    tree = BallTree(candidates, leaf_size=15, metric='haversine')

    # Find closest points and distances
    distances, indices = tree.query(src_points, k=k_neighbors)

    # Transpose to get distances and indices into arrays
    distances = distances.transpose()
    indices = indices.transpose()

    # Get closest indices and distances (i.e. array at index 0)
    # note: for the second closest points, you would take index 1, etc.
    closest = indices[0]
    closest_dist = distances[0]

    # Return indices and distances
    return (closest, closest_dist)


def nearest_neighbor(left_gdf, right_gdf, return_dist=False):
    """
    For each point in left_gdf, find closest point in right GeoDataFrame and return them.

    NOTICE: Assumes that the input Points are in WGS84 projection (lat/lon).
    """

    left_geom_col = left_gdf.geometry.name
    right_geom_col = right_gdf.geometry.name

    # Ensure that index in right gdf is formed of sequential numbers
    right = right_gdf.copy().reset_index(drop=True)

    # Parse coordinates from points and insert them into a numpy array as RADIANS
    left_radians = np.array(left_gdf[left_geom_col].apply(lambda geom: (geom.x * np.pi / 180, geom.y * np.pi / 180)).to_list())
    right_radians = np.array(right[right_geom_col].apply(lambda geom: (geom.x * np.pi / 180, geom.y * np.pi / 180)).to_list())

    # Find the nearest points
    # -----------------------
    # closest ==> index in right_gdf that corresponds to the closest point
    # dist ==> distance between the nearest neighbors (in meters)

    closest, dist = get_nearest(src_points=left_radians, candidates=right_radians)

    # Return points from right GeoDataFrame that are closest to points in left GeoDataFrame
    closest_points = right.loc[closest]

    # Ensure that the index corresponds the one in left_gdf
    closest_points = closest_points.reset_index(drop=True)

    # Add distance if requested
    if return_dist:
        # Convert to meters from radians
        earth_radius = 6371000  # meters
        closest_points['distance'] = dist * earth_radius

            return closest_points


closest_stops = nearest_neighbor(buildings, stops, return_dist=True)
```

We get for each building index the distance to the closest bus stop:

```
    stop_name    stop_lat   stop_lon    stop_id                 geometry      distance
0   Muusantori   60.207490  24.857450   1304138 POINT (24.85745 60.20749)   180.521584
1   Eläintarha   60.192490  24.930840   1171120 POINT (24.93084 60.19249)   372.665221
2   Senaatintori 60.169010  24.950460   1020450 POINT (24.95046 60.16901)   119.425777
3   Veturitie    60.206610  24.929680   1174112 POINT (24.92968 60.20661)   106.762619
```

I'm looking for solution to get every bus stop (can be more than one) in distance below 250 meters for each building.

Thank you for help.

Comment: This kind of questions is perfectly suited for [GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @s.k Yes and No, as GIS tools won't work on huge datasets, that is the reason I'm looking for strictly Python-ish solution.

Comment: GIS tools were some of the first to take on big data, so I'm not sure what you're getting at with that comment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because belongs on gis.se

Comment: Hi @PaulH , I'm reffering to Python tools like scikit-learn, numpy which could help with this problem (and other similar ones, not only spatial). If there will be no one to help, I can move it to gis.se. Closing hard questions is not the answer to everything ...

Comment: This seems like a purely spatial problem and not at all like a machine learning problem to me.

Comment: I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but I think you'll have more luck over on the GIS stack exchange. That's all. It's free advice. Take it for what its worth. If you really want me to think about this, I'm under-employed at the moment and charge $75/hr for spatial and statistical analysis consulting

Comment: Hope you'll find something soon, I know how much it sucks being unemployed .... Best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is a way reusing what has been done with BallTree like in question but with `query_radius` instead. Also it is not in function format but you can still change it easily

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
## here I start with buildings and stops as loaded in the link provided

# variable in meter you can change
radius_max = 250 # meters
# another parameter, in case you want to do with Mars radius ^^
earth_radius = 6371000  # meters

# similar to the method with apply in the tutorial 
# to create left_radians and right_radians, but faster
candidates = np.vstack([stops['geometry'].x.to_numpy(), 
                        stops['geometry'].y.to_numpy()]).T*np.pi/180
src_points = np.vstack([buildings['geometry'].x.to_numpy(), 
                        buildings['geometry'].y.to_numpy()]).T*np.pi/180

# Create tree from the candidate points
tree = BallTree(candidates, leaf_size=15, metric='haversine')
# use query_radius instead
ind_radius, dist_radius = tree.query_radius(src_points, 
                                            r=radius_max/earth_radius, 
                                            return_distance=True)
```

Now you can manipulate the results to get what you want

```
# create a dataframe build with
# index based on row position of the building in buildings
# column row_stop is the row position of the stop
# dist is the distance
closest_dist = pd.concat([pd.Series(ind_radius).explode().rename('row_stop'), 
                          pd.Series(dist_radius).explode().rename('dist')*earth_radius], 
                         axis=1)
print (closest_dist.head())
#  row_stop     dist
#0     1131  180.522
#1      NaN      NaN
#2       64  174.744
#2       61  119.426
#3      532  106.763

# merge the dataframe created above with the original data stops
# to get names, id, ... note: the index must be reset as in closest_dist
# it is position based
closest_stop = closest_dist.merge(stops.reset_index(drop=True), 
                                  left_on='row_stop', right_index=True, how='left')
print (closest_stop.head())
#  row_stop     dist     stop_name  stop_lat  stop_lon    stop_id  \
#0     1131  180.522    Muusantori  60.20749  24.85745  1304138.0   
#1      NaN      NaN           NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN   
#2       64  174.744  Senaatintori  60.16896  24.94983  1020455.0   
#2       61  119.426  Senaatintori  60.16901  24.95046  1020450.0   
#3      532  106.763     Veturitie  60.20661  24.92968  1174112.0   
#
#                    geometry  
#0  POINT (24.85745 60.20749)  
#1                       None  
#2  POINT (24.94983 60.16896)  
#2  POINT (24.95046 60.16901)  
#3  POINT (24.92968 60.20661)
```

Finally join back to buildings

```
# join buildings with reset_index with 
# closest_stop as index in closest_stop are position based
final_df = buildings.reset_index(drop=True).join(closest_stop, rsuffix='_stop')
print (final_df.head(10))
#              name                   geometry row_stop     dist     stop_name  \
# 0            None  POINT (24.85584 60.20727)     1131  180.522    Muusantori   
# 1     Uimastadion  POINT (24.93045 60.18882)      NaN      NaN           NaN   
# 2            None  POINT (24.95113 60.16994)       64  174.744  Senaatintori   
# 2            None  POINT (24.95113 60.16994)       61  119.426  Senaatintori   
# 3  Hartwall Arena  POINT (24.92918 60.20570)      532  106.763     Veturitie   

#    stop_lat  stop_lon    stop_id              geometry_stop  
# 0  60.20749  24.85745  1304138.0  POINT (24.85745 60.20749)  
# 1       NaN       NaN        NaN                       None  
# 2  60.16896  24.94983  1020455.0  POINT (24.94983 60.16896)  
# 2  60.16901  24.95046  1020450.0  POINT (24.95046 60.16901)  
# 3  60.20661  24.92968  1174112.0  POINT (24.92968 60.20661)
```

Comment: In the last DF why there are "None" buildings at index #0 and 2x #2 ? And building with index #1 just don't have bus stop in the radius of 250m right?

Comment: @cincin21 so for the None, I saw when opening the buildings dataframe there was some row without name (None) so it is why you get None at the end too. And yes for row#1, all the nan means no stop within the limit define (250m in this case)

Comment: @cincin21 actually if you look at in your question where you printed `closest_stops` at the end, that row #1, the distance is 372, so it confirm the result found here

Answer (score 0):

To get the closest bus stop within 250m:

```py
filtered_by_distance = closest_stops[closest_stops.distance < 250]
result = buildings.join(filtered_by_distance)
```

For all stops within the radius you need to use [BallTree.query_radius](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.query_radius). But you will need to convert meters to radians.

Comment: Thanks, I will read  on BallTree.query_radius, the first solution won't work as I want every bus stop (could be more than one).